# Unity realtime GI - baking causes odd shadows

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using realtime lighting with baked GI.

I have tried resolutions between 1-20 for these rocks, I've tried chaning UV distance, angle and lightmap scale. Nothing seems to fix these weird shadows. Does anyone know what is causing it? It only occus on about 1% of objects.

[image]

Comment: looks a bit like ambient occlusion - can you verify PostProcessing is off for testing?

Comment: ah omg, ur right! thanks so much, spent the last 2 hours on this... Guess Ill have to make more than 1 post processing asset depending on the scene :)

Comment: You're welcome, I made it an answer - can you accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the result of ambient occlusion - deactivate PostProcessing to see if your baked shadows look fine.